# Change background color when a Popup is shown

Tags: android, popupwindow

I want to make the background darker when a `PopupWindow` is shown. Just like Dolphin Browser does like-

**Before the PopupWindow**

[image: Look at the background color before the PopupWindow is shown]

**After the PopupWindow**

[image: And now see the background color after the PopupWindow is shown.]

The background color is darker than what it was. So, how can we do this?

Answer (score 5):

In your xml file add something like this with width and height as 'match_parent'.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bac_dim_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#C0000000"
        android:visibility="gone" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

In your activity oncreate

```
//setting background dim when showing popup
back_dim_layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.bac_dim_layout);
```

Finally make visible when you show your popupwindow and make its visible gone when you exit popupwindow.

```
back_dim_layout.setVisibility(View.Visible);
back_dim_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong... you can create an activity with listview.... and put the theme as dialog in its manifest like this..

```
 <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

this will make the background darker..

Comment: Okay but... Why to change the code and make a `PopupWindow` an activity.

Comment: because , your popup will be an activity it will have its ownbackground..... which is dark by default... giving the required effect..

Comment: Agree, but am saying why to call an activity when you have the PopupWindow control with you. Anyways, if nothing works, I'll go with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this code if your **popup is an activity** then it will help definetly.
make a mystyle.xml file in **values folder** of your project and make these changes.

```
<resources> 
   <style name="customStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
     <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
   </style>
</resources>
```

do this change in 
**menifest.xml**

```
<activity android:name="yourActivity" android:theme="@style/customStyle"></activity>
```

Comment: As I mentioned above, I use `PopupWindow` control and NOT `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

```
fun setBackgroundAlpha(activity: Activity, bgAlpha: Float) {
    val lp: WindowManager.LayoutParams = activity.getWindow().getAttributes()
    lp.alpha = bgAlpha
    activity.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND)
    activity.getWindow().setAttributes(lp)
}
```